# Goでのeval

Tags: python, go

GoでPythonのevalのようなものはありますか?
文字列の式を評価してくれるものです

python

```
x = eval("1+1")
print(x) # 2
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`go/types` package に `Eval()` 関数があります。以下は "1 + 1" の例です。

https://play.golang.org/p/2kTkuWjYYz

ソースコードの `go/src/go/types/eval_test.go` が参考になるかと思います。